# Why NSScrollView freeze application when large string data are inserted

Tags: swift, nsscrollview

I have these lines in my code

```
scrvParsedJSON.documentView?.selectAll(nil)
scrvParsedJSON.documentView?.deleteForward(nil)
scrvParsedJSON.documentView?.insertText(jsonString)
scrvParsedJSON.documentView?.scrollToBeginningOfDocument(nil)
```

where scrvParsedJSON is NSScrollView and jsonString is String variable containing approx 4 MB of text. Application got frozen when the code above is executed and start to consume more and more memory. It works fine if jsonString contains just a few characters.
Do I use NSScrollView wrongly?

Comment: Is `scrvParsedJSON.documentView` a `NSTextView`?

Comment: Yes, it's NSTextView.

Comment: Do you do anything with the `NSScrollView`?

Comment: No it`s just to display the text.

Comment: Is the scroll view or the text view freezing the app? Which statement makes the app freeze?

Comment: This line causes the issue scrvParsedJSON.documentView?.insertText(jsonString)

Comment: `insertText(_:)` is a method of `NSTextView` and is deprecated, the documentation says "This method is the entry point for inserting text typed by the user and is generally not suitable for other purposes. Programmatic modification of the text is best done by operating on the text storage directly.". Is `jsonString` a `NSString` or a `NSAttributedString`?

Comment: NSString or rather String

Comment: I tried your code and I don't see any runtime issues.

Comment: How big text you tried? I have no issue if it's in kB but it becomes worse for 4 MB and more.

Comment: I tried 16 MB, scrolling isn't always smooth but it doesn't freeze for long. I think the problem is `NSTextView` related. Did you try switching off the Linguistics, Substitution and Editing settings? Do you get any build warnings? Is it possible to reproduce the issue in a small test project?